# Is there currently any way to install mypy for python 3.7 and use with PyDev?

Tags: python-3.x, pydev, mypy

I tried to install mypy with "phyton -m pip install mypy" but it fails with an error about typed_ast that says it needs Visual C++ compiler but after installing that the error remains. I found several similar reports and notes that it can't be fixed due to the typed_ast thing, I don't know any details about that.

Is there a way to install mypy manually? Just copy a bunch of files somewhere?

I use Windows 10, Python 3.7, I updated to the latest pip.

Any help or hint is welcome

Thanks a lot

Martin

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself.
I have python 3.7-32 installed and there is no appropriate wheel for typed -ast for this. This video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZrThBBpFlo
explains the problem and also gives a solution. I installed a 32-bit wheel from the link given and then installed mypy again and it finished successfully.
Now I will try mypy.
Good luck